# Nervous about concert!

Tags: orchestra, cello

I have a concert tomorrow and im really nervous, i have practiced many MANY hours but I don't think iv'e practiced enough for the concert, or maybe it just that im really nervous....any tips?

I play cello

Comment: This is a Q&A site rather than a discussion based one.You need to ask a specific question which has a correct answer rather than one which invites discussion.

Comment: It’s when you’re not nervous that you should be worried.

Comment: You're in good company!  Even the pros often feel the way you're feeling now!